# Implementation of Fermat's primality test

Tags: java, math, primes, biginteger

Who wants to help me with my homework?

I'm try to implement [Fermat's primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test#Algorithm_and_running_time) in Java using BigIntegers. My implementation is as follows, but unfortunately it doesn't work.  Any ideas?

```
public static boolean checkPrime(BigInteger n, int maxIterations)
{
    if (n.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        return false;

    BigInteger a;
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++)
    {
        a = new BigInteger(n.bitLength() - 1, rand);
        a = a.modPow(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n);

        if (!a.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm new to BigIntegers.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have better luck if you spell out what "doesn't work" looks like.

Comment: By "doesn't work" I mean that it doesn't give a proper result.  For example, when I test it against prime numbers such as 2, 3, 5, and 7, it returns "false" when it should return "true."

Comment: Have you checked that a = new BigInteger(n.bitLength() - 1, rand); is indeed a normal value when printing, and rand is correctly initialized from 1 to n ( I don't see that part) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the particular BigInteger constructor is reasonable, but you should use a [rejection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) to select a fermat base a. Here is a slight modification of your method in a class which also uses exactly one Random object:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class FermatTestExample
{

    private final static Random rand = new Random();

    private static BigInteger getRandomFermatBase(BigInteger n)
    {
        // Rejection method: ask for a random integer but reject it if it isn't
        // in the acceptable set.

        while (true)
        {
            final BigInteger a = new BigInteger (n.bitLength(), rand);
            // must have 1 <= a < n
            if (BigInteger.ONE.compareTo(a) <= 0 && a.compareTo(n) < 0)
            {
                return a;
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkPrime(BigInteger n, int maxIterations)
    {
        if (n.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++)
        {
            BigInteger a = getRandomFermatBase(n);
            a = a.modPow(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n);

            if (!a.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.printf("checkprime(2) is %b%n", checkPrime(BigInteger.valueOf(2L), 20));
        System.out.printf("checkprime(5) is %b%n", checkPrime(BigInteger.valueOf(5L), 20));
        System.out.printf("checkprime(7) is %b%n", checkPrime(BigInteger.valueOf(7L), 20));
        System.out.printf("checkprime(9) is %b%n", checkPrime(BigInteger.valueOf(9L), 20));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a should be "pick a randomly in the range (1, n − 1]" and I don't really see that happening. You could print a to check that.

As for how to do that:

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(random.nextInt(n-2)+2);
```

e.g. You shouldn't use the BigInteger constructor with a Random argument; that's just a source of randomness, but *a* should be a random *value*.

The 'random.nextInt(n-1)+1' comes from the definition of [nextInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) which, given argument k, returns a random value 0 up to and including k-1. And you want *a* to be larger than 1 and smaller than n.

Comment: Good point -- I think that is the problem.  However, how can one apply a range to a Random object in Java?

Comment: @DT3 You get the most points at the easy, obvious questions. Lots of people have an answer to that and read your answer.

Comment: This answer assumes `n` is an int, which it is not.

Comment: I jumped the gun on marking the question as answered. The issue, as GregS says, is that "n" is a BigInteger, not an int.