# Reading /dev/urandom and generating a random integer

Tags: php, security, math

I am trying to create a function that generates a random integer out of the bytes I get from /dev/urandom. I am doing this in PHP and it currently looks like:

```
    public static function getRandomInteger($min, $max)
    {
        // First we need to determine how many bytes we need to construct $min-$max range.
        $difference = $max-$min;
        $bytesNeeded = ceil($difference/256);

        $randomBytes = self::getRandomBytes($bytesNeeded);

        // Let's sum up all bytes.
        $sum = 0;
        for ($a = 0; $a < $bytesNeeded; $a++)
            $sum += ord($randomBytes[$a]);

        // Make sure we don't push the limits.
        $sum = $sum % ($difference);

        return $sum + $min;
    }
```

Everything works great except that I think it's not calculating the values exactly fair. For example, if you want to have a random value between 0 and 250, it receives one byte and mods it with 250 so the values of 0-6 are more likely to appear than the values of 7-250. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use `rand()`? It's tried, tested, and you don't have to waste time on something like this.

Comment: I am not happy with the quality of pseudorandom numbers it produces. And the second reason is that I am doing this for more academic than practical purposes.

Comment: To answer your last point, you should not MOD it. Scale it with `*250/255` to not skew the distribution.

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes sense. Is it then perfect?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027225/implementation-of-fermats-primality-test/4027871#4027871) to another question where I recommend using a rejection method, and give some Java code that shows how. You should be able to go from Java -> php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) If you don't need cryptographically secure random numbers, simply use `mt_rand`. It will probably suffice for your needs.

b) If you want to stick with your algorithm: Do some remapping: `return round($min + $sum / pow(256, $bytesNeeded) * ($max - $min))`.

c) As you can see, this requires `round`ing. That will lead to a not perfectly uniform distribution, I think (though I am not sure about this). Probably the best way is to get the random number as a float and then scale it. Though I have no idea how you get a float from `/dev/urandom`. That's why I stick with `mt_rand` and `lcg_value`.

Comment: I already have implemented a perfect float() method, but I think using it would limit myself to the precision of float? Would it not theoretically be better to implement it without the float, although I am sure that 2**52 precision that floats have is enough to make a good getRandomInteger() method?

Answer (score -1):

I would read `$difference` bytes from /dev/urandom `mod $difference` and then add `$min`

Then make sure `$max` isn't higher than that number.