# Can't Generate Large Prime Numbers

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm trying to generate large prime numbers in Java. I use BigIntegers for this. Here is my code to generate and store 10 prime numbers inside an array.

```
    public static void primeGenerator() {
    BigInteger[] primeList = new BigInteger[10];
    BigInteger startLine = new BigInteger("10");
    int startPower = 6;
    BigInteger endLine = new BigInteger("10");
    int endPower = 9;
    int j = 0;
    for (BigInteger i = fastExp(startLine,startPower); 
            i.compareTo(fastExp(endLine,endPower)) <= 0; 
            i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        if (checkPrimeFermat(i) == true && j < 10) {
            primeList[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(primeList[0]);
    System.out.println(primeList[1]);
    System.out.println(primeList[2]);
    System.out.println(primeList[3]);
    System.out.println(primeList[4]);
    System.out.println(primeList[5]);
    System.out.println(primeList[6]);
    System.out.println(primeList[7]);
    System.out.println(primeList[8]);
    System.out.println(primeList[9]);


}
```

I wrote my own fastExp function to generate numbers faster. Here are my other functions.

```
public static BigInteger getRandomFermatBase(BigInteger n)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        while (true)
        {
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger (n.bitLength(), rand);

            if (BigInteger.ONE.compareTo(a) <= 0 && a.compareTo(n) < 0)
            {
                return a;
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkPrimeFermat(BigInteger n)
    {
        if (n.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            BigInteger a = getRandomFermatBase(n);
            a = a.modPow(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n);

            if (!a.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        primeGenerator();



        }

       public static BigInteger fastExp (BigInteger x, int n){
            BigInteger result=x;
            int pow2=powof2leN(n);
            int residue= n-pow2;
            for(int i=1; i<pow2 ; i=i*2){
                result=result.multiply(result);
                }
            for(int i=0 ; i<residue; i++){
                result=result.multiply(x);          
            }
            return result;

        }

        private static int powof2leN(int n) {
            for(int i=1; i<=n; i=i*2){
                if(i*2>2)
                    return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }    

}
```

So the problem is when I try it with small numbers (for example startPower=3, endPower=5) it generates and prints prime numbers. But when I try it with big numbers (for example startPower=5, endPower=7) it doesn't generate anything. How can I improve my code to work with large numbers?

Thank you

Comment: Can you be a little more specific than "it doesn't generate anything"?  Something like "I passed `x` to method `foo()` and was stuck in a while loop forever" or "I passed in `y` to method `bar()` and got back `null`".

Comment: A shortcut for this might be to use use `BigInteger.nextProbablePrime()`.

Comment: It simply doesn't print anything. If it can't find prime numbers, it's need to print null for every item but it doesn't. I left my computer for 30minutes it looks like stuck in a loop or something I don't know

Comment: You can figure out whether it's stuck in a loop or it's just taking forever to compute by putting some print statements in there and seeing if the numbers are converging.

Comment: What is the purpose of `powof2leN()`? It's functionally equivalent to `(n > 1) ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: Sounds like it's just spending a lot of time going through a long sequence of composite numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I would like to point out that you did not write this code. You stole it [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027871/3224483) and claimed that you wrote it, which is incredibly unethical.

---

The code is correct. It's just slow. As you increase the power, the code takes increasingly longer. There are two reasons why this occurs:

1. The Fermat test takes increasingly longer to apply.
2. BigInteger operations take increasingly longer to execute.

The Fermat test grows like O(k × log2n × log log n × log log log n). BigInteger's addition and subtraction grow like O(n). Obviously, BigInteger is what is slowing you down.

Below is a profile of your code with the power set from 5 to 7.

[image]

If you want your code to produce larger and larger primes, you should focus on reducing the number of operations you do on BigIntegers. Here is one such improvement:

- Take `n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)` outside of your `for` loop. The result does not need to be calculated many times.

Further suggestions will have to come from the Mathematics folks over on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler solution for finding large primes -

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("9001");//or whatever big number you want to start with
BigInteger[] primes = new BigInteger[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    primes[i]=big=big.nextProbablePrime();
}
```

It has some limitations outlined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#nextProbablePrime%28%29), but based on your code it should be more than enough.

Comment: I can't use nextProbablePrime function because it's a homework assingment :(

Comment: Ah... I suspected as such.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd)` constructor

```
BigInteger b= new BigInteger(20, 1, new Random());
```

It will generate a prime number for you. `bitLength` specifies the number of digits you want in your BigInteger, `certainity` specifies the amount of certainity you want that your BigInteger should be prime.

Comment: dear downvoter, shoulndn't you had left a comment here?